# I have a catch 22 here! No internet unless I update

Tags: command-line, usb, internet-connection, usb-modem

I have a usb internet tether, but it will not work in Ubuntu, unless I download something in the terminal, but I also can not get internet until I get this device working. I am able to use my Windows side on the internet, that's how I am doing this, but not with Ubuntu side.

Is there any way, that allows me to download a packet (that i have directions for) while using Windows side, in the command-line?

This is the fix I found for my usb device, that I can't do without internet.
To get it working, make sure your iPhone is not plugged in. Then open up terminal and add the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev libimobiledevice-utils ipheth-utils gvfs
```

After this is done, turn MyWi application back on and plug it in. It will not seem to work if you have it plugged in, and then turn it on.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in that I recently stumbled upon by another user here [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) which will allow you to use an internet capable machine to put the updates onto a USB drive then apply those updates to your computer via USB

Answer (score 2):

What about manually downloading all the packages from the ppa and installing them in your computer?.

If you click on the view package detail in the ppa web [page](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+index?field.series_filter=lucid), you should be able to download the debs one by one. Please check that you download the Lucid packages if you are using 10.04, and Karmic if you are using 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

If your router has a wired connection you can just use that (assuming your laptop also has a wired ethernet socket, if not you can get USB to wired ethernet adaptors for £10-£20 these days, the apple one works out of the box with ubuntu)